# Efficiently remove similar strings in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, duplicates, similarity

I have a dataframe with lyrics of songs in one column (one song per row) and I know that there are several duplicates in there which are not exactly the same but have some differences in the spelling. I wrote the following code which works but is really slow, as the lyrics are quite long strings and the dataframe has over 1000 rows. Is there a more elegant / efficient way of coding?

```
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def mark_duplicates_within_column(df, column, alpha = 0.95):
    df['duplicate'] = [False]*df.shape[0]

    for i, val_a in enumerate(tqdm_notebook(df[column])):
        if df['duplicate'].iloc[i] == True:
            continue
        for j, val_b in enumerate(df[column]):
            if df['duplicate'].iloc[j] == True:
                continue
            if val_a == val_b:
                continue
            elif similar(val_a, val_b) > alpha:
                df['duplicate'].iloc._setitem_with_indexer(j, True)
                
    return df
```

Here is a toy example of what I want to achieve:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['names'], data = ['Thomas Müller', 'Thomas Muller', 'Toni Kroos'])
>>> mark_duplicates_within_column(df, 'names', alpha=0.9)
    
    names       duplicate
0   Thomas Müller   False
1   Thomas Muller   True
2   Toni Kroos  False
```

Comment: If you rewrite your function to work on a single row, then you can use `apply` to execute the function in parallel for every row. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you mean? I can't figure out how to use `apply` to compare two different rows within a column

Comment: The main problem I spot is that you have designed this in O(n^2): For each row you are inspecting all other rows. You could shorten that in practice by limiting the search by applying a smart way to sort the data-frame and just searching the surroundings. Another direction would be to tokenize the strings and building a reverse index: For each word you store the rows where it occurs, allowing for a comparison of shared tokens in O(1)